# Merging multiple CSV rows with mostly empty fields into single row per timestamp

Tags: bash, python-2.7, perl, awk, sed

I've got a problem converting an "ugly" csv into a "pretty" one.
e.g., I have:

```
something,epochtime,time-human-readable,some,header,for,the,values,here
same,time-a,don-t_care,a,b,,,,
same,time-a,don-t_care,,,,,c,
same,time-a,don-t_care,,,,,,d
same,time-a,don-t_care,,,e,f,,
same,time-b,don-t_care,g,h,,,,
same,time-b,don-t_care,,,i,j,,
same,time-b,don-t_care,,,,,,k
same,time-b,don-t_care,,,,,l,
same,time-c,don-t_care,,,m,n,,
same,time-c,don-t_care,,,,,o,
same,time-c,don-t_care,p,q,,,,
same,time-c,don-t_care,,,,,,r
```

But what I need is:

```
something,epochtime,time-human-readable,some,header,for,the,values,here
same,time-a,don-t_care,a,b,e,f,c,d
same,time-b,don-t_care,g,h,i,j,l,k
same,time-c,don-t_care,p,q,m,n,o,r
```

Data behaviour:

- Columns in question contain signed-integer or float (except first and third column which are of type string and not part of the problem).
- Always exactly 1 value per column and epochtime. (One could interpret empty fields as 0 and sum all values in one column belonging to a single epochtime.)
- Values to one epochtime spread across the same number of lines every time.
- Values belonging to a single epochtime ***might*** always appear spread across the rows in the same pattern (unlike the example) ... but that's not guaranteed.

I tried to solve this problem with my limited skill using sed / awk but to no avail.

Any solution that can be executed by crontab is welcome, while bash / sed / awk / perl / python or any "apt-get install ..." capable command-line tool is preferred. Host OS is XUbuntu 16.04 LTS.

Addendum: (2018-10-16 13:55 UTC)

- Rows are sorted chronological according to epochtime
- Values are grouped by epochtime
- Even though first and third column contain string, it consists of Letters, Numbers and `-` or `_`, no whitespace or `,` --> no string-headache
  i.e. `dummy,1539697764,2018-10-16_13-49-24,p,q,,,,`

Comment: The first line has `a,b` only. The first time the third field has something is `e` and you use that to fill the slot in the first line. But, next comes `i` in that field, a few lines down. Do you always use the first that comes along? Then, the line with `p,q` uses `m` to fill the third field-- which appeared in an _earlier_ line.  What is the general rule? If an item to fill a field has been seen (and wasn't used) then use that one, otherwise the first next? What when there are more unused items for a field, which ones do you use? Can one item be re-used to fill spots in multiple lines?

Comment: Could you include the code you have tried in your question, please?

Comment: @zdim, Combine rows with same value in second field.

Comment: @ikegami  The row with `e` that's used to fill the first row (`a,b`) has nothing in the second field? Or am I missing stuff ...?

Comment: @zdim It looks like everything resets when there's a new value in the time column.

Comment: @Shawn Ah, I didn't read the third bullet carefully.  Then one can just keep a buffer and collapse it into a line once epoch time changes (if we're given uniqueness and completeness of field entries)

Comment: @zdiff, hum? Every row has a value in the second field (`epochtime`), either `time-a`, `time-b` or `time-c`.

Comment: @blue_bandana, The two posted snippets assume the rows are grouped by `epochtime`. Is that the case, you didn't say it was.

Comment: epochtime is chronological and values are grouped by time.
As zdim mentioned, "uniqueness and completeness of field entries" is given.

Comment: @ikegami Eh, I was counting those fields that are up for grabs. You are right, lines are grouped for the (same) value in the second field.  I skimmed over that third bullet too quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
$2 != prev { if (NR>1) prt(); prev=$2 }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i != "") {
            rec[i] = $i
        }
    }
}
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", rec[i], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    delete rec
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
something,epochtime,time-human-readable,some,header,for,the,values,here
same,time-a,don-t_care,a,b,e,f,c,d
same,time-b,don-t_care,g,h,i,j,l,k
same,time-c,don-t_care,p,q,m,n,o,r
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl version, using a CSV parser instead of naive splitting on commas in order to be more robust - you mention some of the columns are strings, so this will handle cases where they have embedded commas and such.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
# Install the following non-core modules through your
# OS package manager or favorite CPAN client.
use List::MoreUtils qw/pairwise/;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ auto_diag => 2, blank_is_undef => 1 });
my $header = <>;
print $header;
my $merged = $csv->getline(\*ARGV);
while (my $cols = $csv->getline(\*ARGV)) {
  if ($merged->[1] ne $cols->[1]) {
    $csv->say(\*STDOUT, $merged);
    $merged = $cols;
  } else {
    $merged = [ pairwise { $a // $b } @$merged, @$cols ];
  }
}
$csv->say(\*STDOUT, $merged);
```

running it:

```
$ perl merge.pl data.csv
something,epochtime,time-human-readable,some,header,for,the,values,here
same,time-a,don-t_care,a,b,e,f,c,d
same,time-b,don-t_care,g,h,i,j,l,k
same,time-c,don-t_care,p,q,m,n,o,r
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Perl solution:

```
open $CSV, "<" , "ugly.csv";
@R=();
  while (<$CSV>) {
      if ($.==1 ) { print ; next; }
      chomp;
      @F=split(/,/,$_);
      $k=join(",",@F[0..2]);
      if( $k ne $prevk ) { @R=() }
      push(@R,@F[3..9],"|");
      $hash{"$k"}=join(",",@R);
      $prevk=$k;
    }
foreach $val (sort keys %hash)
{
 @arr=split(/\|/,$hash{$val});
 $x=join("",reverse sort @arr);
 $x=~s/(^[,])|([,]{2,})/$1 eq "," ? "" : ","/eg;
 print "$val,$x\n";
}
```

Shell Output:

```
$ perl -f ugly_csv.pl
something,epochtime,time-human-readable,some,header,for,the,values,here
same,time-a,don-t_care,a,b,e,f,c,d,
same,time-b,don-t_care,g,h,i,j,l,k,
same,time-c,don-t_care,p,q,m,n,o,r,
```